# Why can't I place a variable into my array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Is it possible to have a variable in an array as a value in PHP.  For example:

```
'arraykey' => "$varname",
```

It does not seem to work and I can't find any info about this anywhere.  Maybe because its just not possible?  Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but the code you have is not for creating an array (at least it is not complete). Please post a complete example.

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a reference: &$varname . I haven't tried it myself so I don't know if that's possible or not.

Comment: It was the quotes causing a problem. Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$array['item'] = $varname;
```

There are lots of use-cases in the spec: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but not using double quotes. It will cause the value of the variable to be inserted in the string instead.

Use this:

```
$cow = "Mooo";
$varname = 'cow';

$a = array('arrayitem' => '$varname');

$var = $a['arrayitem'];

echo $$var;
```

Or rather: don't use it. It won't make your code very readable. But it's possible, as you can see. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[] = $var;  
$array['item'] = $var;
```

Dont use $variables inside "" and ''s

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible, but you do not need the quotes around the variable name.

```
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
$z = "pasta";
$myVars = array(
   'x' => $x,
   'y' => $y,
   'z' => $z
);
print_r($myVars);
```